# Fresh download and start of Neo4j 1.9.9: fails to start

Tags: neo4j

Steps to recreate:

```
Downloaded the tar.gz file to Ubuntu 14.04
tar zxvf neo4j.tar.gz
sudo neo4j/bin/neo4j install
sudo service neo4j-service start
```

Getting the following error:

```
16:02:44.205 [main] INFO  o.n.s.enterprise.EnterpriseNeoServer - Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@6c04c230' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:530)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:157)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:123)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:284)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:116)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:96)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:207)
    at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseDatabase$DatabaseMode$1.createDatabase(EnterpriseDatabase.java:42)
    at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseDatabase.start(EnterpriseDatabase.java:78)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:170)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:103)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:57)
```

For full stack trace see:
https://gist.github.com/henry74/6a14fa76fffabf6d4313

Comment: Have you set the max number of open files according to http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/linux-performance-guide.html#_setting_the_number_of_open_files ?

Comment: Yes, did that already.  Don't get the MAX 1024 warning on startup.